# Changing defaults doesn't change setting in system preferences window

Tags: macos, system-preferences, plist

I'm trying to enable tap to click from a bash script using:

```
defaults write com.apple.AppleMultitouchTrackpad Clicking -int 1
```

When I open the Trackpad section on the System Preferences panel, the checkbox is disabled for the setting but it is working. I can tap to click.

What do I need to change in order to show that the setting has been modified in the System Preferences panel?

Answer (score 0):

The property `Clicking` is a boolean value.
The property list is read at login.
If the System Preferences dialog is open when the property is set via the `defaults write` command, it could silently fail.
Apart from the `com.apple.AppleMultitouchTrackpad.plist` file, the same property is used in `com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad`. I'm not sure if you are using the external Trackpad, but no harm in setting both values.

So for good measure I do:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Preferences" to quit'
killall cfprefsd
defaults write "com.apple.AppleMultitouchTrackpad" "Clicking" -bool true
defaults write "com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad"  "Clicking" -bool true
```

And then just logout and back in.
:)